# How to disable notifications on background state?

Tags: react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I use react-native-firebase/messaging: 6.4.0 and react-native-push-notification: 3.2.1
In background/quit state i get two notifications:
1. Default notification from react-native-firebase
2. Custom  notification from react-native-push-notification

my index.js code:

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async message => {
  pushService.showPush(message);
});
```

How to disable notifications from react-native-firebase/messaging on background state?

Comment: Got any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?